# Android studio 3 beta 2 Build failed

Tags: java, android, build, kotlin

When i start my First Kotlin project & install **Android studio 3 beta 2** 
i get this  problem

> Error:(29, 38) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'layout_width' with value '@dimen/abc_dropdownitem_icon_width').
>
> Error:(20, 26) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'alpha' with value '@dimen/highlight_alpha_material_colored').
>
> Error:(29, 38) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'layout_width' with value '@dimen/abc_dropdownitem_icon_width').
>
> Error:(59, 39) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'layout_width' with value '@dimen/abc_dropdownitem_icon_width').
>
> Error:(20, 26) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'alpha' with value '@dimen/highlight_alpha_material_colored').
>
> Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing
>   process /home/programmer/Android/Sdk/build-tools/26.0.1/aapt with
>   arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I
>   /home/programmer/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-26/android.jar -M
>   /home/programmer/AndroidStudioProjects/MyFirstAppKotlin/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
>   -S /home/programmer/AndroidStudioProjects/MyFirstAppKotlin/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug
>   -m -J /home/programmer/AndroidStudioProjects/MyFirstAppKotlin/app/build/generated/source/r/debug
>   -F /home/programmer/AndroidStudioProjects/MyFirstAppKotlin/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/resources-debug.ap_
>   --custom-package com.example.programmer.myfirstappkotlin -0 apk --output-text-symbols /home/programmer/AndroidStudioProjects/MyFirstAppKotlin/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug
>   --no-version-vectors}
>
> Error:com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while
>   executing process /home/programmer/Android/Sdk/build-tools/26.0.1/aapt
>   with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I
>   /home/programmer/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-26/android.jar -M
>   /home/programmer/AndroidStudioProjects/MyFirstAppKotlin/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
>   -S /home/programmer/AndroidStudioProjects/MyFirstAppKotlin/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug
>   -m -J /home/programmer/AndroidStudioProjects/MyFirstAppKotlin/app/build/generated/source/r/debug
>   -F /home/programmer/AndroidStudioProjects/MyFirstAppKotlin/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/resources-debug.ap_
>   --custom-package com.example.programmer.myfirstappkotlin -0 apk --output-text-symbols /home/programmer/AndroidStudioProjects/MyFirstAppKotlin/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug
>   --no-version-vectors}
>
> Error:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   '/home/programmer/Android/Sdk/build-tools/26.0.1/aapt'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 1
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
> > Failed to execute aapt

Thank you for help .

Comment: Add your build.gradle to the question. No one would be able to help you by only pasting the error log.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the line

> ext.kotlin_version

in the build.gradle - project by

> ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4'